# How can I set the order of loading files in the form for input type="file" multiple?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a drag file preview area in which I set the key attribute to the pictures. I want, depending on this attribute, to specify the order in which these files appear on the site. How can I pass this attribute on form?

```js
$("#fileUpload").change(function() {
  handleFiles(this.files);
});

function handleFiles(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    let elements = [];
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.id = i + 1;
    img.file = file;
    $(img).attr('key', i + 1);
    elements = '<li><span class="img-move">' + (i + 1) + '</span><div class="img-wrapper draggable-element d-' + (i + 1) + '"><span class="img-delete"><i class="fa fa-close "></i></span></div></li>';
    $('#images').append(elements);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
      return function(e) {
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    })(img);
    $(`.img-wrapper.d-${i + 1}`).append(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

}
```

This is my code for the preview area.